# how do we delete sessions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

is there another way to delete sessions variable? i was thinking of sessions = nil

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Setting a session value:

```
@session[:greeting] = "Hello world!"
```

Reading a session value:

```
@session[:greeting] # => "Hello world!"
```

Deleting a single session value:

```
@session.delete :greeting
```

Clearing an entire session:

```
reset_session
```

Comment: I've never seen @session as an instance variable, always just session[:key] (without the @ like a local variable). Is this the same thing?